# Как на C# создать систему синхронизации файлов типа Google Drive, Mega, Yandex Disk?

Tags: c#, .net, облако, synchronized

Я хочу разобраться в базовых вещах, как работают системы синхронизации файлов типа Google Disk, Mega, Yandex Disk.
Хочу создать 
-Сервер
-Клиент

Нужно, как и в других системах, при изменении,добавлении,удалении файлов и папок- сливать данные на сервер и потом клиентам.
Пока могу мониторить папку на изменения, а вот по какому протоколу лучше пересылать данные и как это всё организовать?

Comment: Сколько будет клиентов у сервера? Они находятся в одной сети, или файлы должны передаватся через интернет? Есть ли какие-то требования к безопасности?

Comment: @"Ivan Tyshchenko" клиентов несколько (не 1). Для себя- так что, нагрузок больших не будет. Доступ по интернету. Можно без шифрований, что б не усложнялось (хотя, если есть с шифрованием примеры, то тоже интересно разобраться)

Comment: протокол для передачи файлов всегда был FTP/FTPS/SFTP, как вариант HTTP/HTTPS. Примеров работы с ними довольно много в сети. Сервер реализовать можно массой способов, можно использовать даже WCF, конкретика выбирается исходя из конкретных требований и тестов производительности. Самое сложное , на мой взгляд, это оповещение клиентов об обновлениях на сервере, но это тоже решаемо разными способами. В чем именно проблема то? Универсального правильного решения на все случаи жизни нет, так что выбирать что и как все равно вам.

Comment: если лень разбираться со стандартными протоколами, можно и на голых сокетах все собрать, но это довольно муторное занятие и все равно в итоге получится самодельный вариант одного из стандартных протоколов и не менее стандартного сервера, только со своими самодельными тараканами в N-ом количестве. Начните с синхронизации на уровне папок файловой системы, а потом добавите прослойку для работы через инет.

Comment: @rdorn вот в уведомлениях как раз были сложности,но я реализовал на вебсоккетах и сервер уведомляет,что есть обновление.Фактически,как я понял-ставлю ftp сервер на сервере,а клиенты закачивают туда либо скачивают.Клиенты за натом.А управлять им и говорить,что сделать-я буду через вебсоккет（ну либо просто соккет）.Получается-как то так

Comment: @rdorn и надо получается на клиентах держать sqlite базу данных,где хранить структуру каталогов и файлов（либо путь）с временем изменения,в случае,если клиент оффлайн и потом сравнивать время последнего обновления и если разница,то закачать.Или как это реализуется?Что,если чел на клиенте взял и поставил время “с потолка” и тогда timestamp не будет совпадать с серверным?И еще вопрос-какой протокол наиболее быстрый?ftp что-то на глаз не отличается самой быстрой скоростью и качать фильм им наверное-не лучший вариант...или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего реализовать что-то из стандартных протоколов, к примеру - HTTP, WebDAV, или FTP. Тогда эти протоколы пришелся реализовывать один раз и только на клиенте, так как для сервера у вас уже будет огромное количество ПО.

Comment: проблемка еще в том,что клиент Х за Nat-ом и как он узнает,что клиент У обновил данные и сейчас они уже на сервере?А по поводу WebDaw,я так и не разобрался,как поставить сервер на Windows 10....а так хотелось....(